# Match multiple lines of text with specific format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, text-extraction

I am sending a few telnet cmds to a device and reading back its result values in a array.

I need to filter the data, but I'm not sure if `preg_split()` or `preg_match()` is better suited.

After isolating the desired rows of text, I need to store several portions of text in a mysql table -- for each row.

All the results that need to be stored are formatted like: `0/0 x x xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx x x x x x`.

Below is the code that I am using, but it's just filtering the first array column.

```
 $show_pon[0] = "show ont info 1 all";
 $show_pon[1] = "show ont info 2 all";
 $show_pon[2] = "show ont info 3 all";
 $show_pon[3] = "show ont info 4 all";
 $show_pon[4] = "show ont info 5 all";
 $show_pon[5] = "show ont info 6 all";
 $show_pon[6] = "show ont info 7 all";
 $show_pon[7] = "show ont info 8 all";
 $show_pon[8] = "show ont info 9 all";
 $show_pon[9] = "show ont info 10 all";
 $show_pon[10] = "show ont info 11 all";
 $show_pon[11] = "show ont info 12 all";
 $show_pon[12] = "show ont info 13 all";
 $show_pon[13] = "show ont info 14 all";
 $show_pon[14] = "show ont info 15 all";
 $show_pon[15] = "show ont info 16 all";   
 
 $telnet->DoCommand($show_pon, $data_response);
 
 $sections = preg_split('/-{50,}\s*\r?\n/s', $data_response);
```

Its actually sending 16 different cmds.. and the output reply to array $sections

the output below is..

```
 Array 
 ( 
 [0] => show ont info 1 all 
 [1] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [2] => 0/0 1 1 AC:4E:91:A6:CF:F5 active online success match VILERMINA-. 
 [3] => Total: 1, online 1 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 2 all 
 [4] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [5] => 0/0 2 1 E0:E8:E6:4E:62:58 active online success match CLOVES-NAV. 
 [6] => Total: 1, online 1 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 3 all 
 [7] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [8] => 0/0 3 1 E0:67:B3:93:F1:97 active online success match 0/0 3 2 18:C5:8A:B0:19:4F active online success match 
 [9] => Total: 2, online 2 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 4 all 
 [10] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [11] => 0/0 4 1 E0:67:B3:A6:45:E1 active online success match Jessica-Si. 0/0 4 2 E0:67:B3:7E:20:05 active online success match onu-id-2 0/0 4 3 E0:67:B3:7D:F8:F9 active online success match onu-id-3 0/0 4 4 E0:E8:E6:4E:69:B8 active online success match onu-id-4 
 [12] => Total: 4, online 4 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 5 all 
 [13] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [14] => 0/0 5 1 C4:70:0B:26:B9:38 active online success match 0/0 5 2 E0:67:B3:88:33:E2 active online success match 0/0 5 3 E0:E8:E6:4E:70:B8 active powerdown initial initial 0/0 5 4 C4:70:0B:26:5C:28 active online success match 0/0 5 5 E0:E8:E6:4E:75:C8 active online success match 0/0 5 6 E0:E8:E6:4E:69:C0 active online success match 0/0 5 7 E0:67:B3:93:EF:D5 active online success match 
 [15] => Total: 7, online 6 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 6 all 
 [16] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [17] => 0/0 6 1 E0:67:B3:88:3D:57 active online success match 0/0 6 2 E0:E8:E6:4E:71:08 active online success match 0/0 6 3 E0:E8:E6:4E:74:78 active online success match 
 [18] => Total: 3, online 3 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 7 all 
 [19] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [20] => 0/0 7 1 00:6D:61:59:D8:48 active online success match 0/0 7 2 E0:E8:E6:4E:55:20 active online success match 
 [21] => Total: 2, online 2 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 8 all 
 [22] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [23] => 0/0 8 1 E0:E8:E6:4E:69:E0 active online success match 0/0 8 2 E0:E8:E6:4E:70:08 active online success match 
 [24] => Total: 2, online 2 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 9 all 
 [25] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [26] => 0/0 9 1 E0:E8:E6:4E:62:78 active online success match 0/0 9 2 E0:67:B3:A6:58:0F active online success match 0/0 9 3 9C:28:EF:01:AE:99 active online success match 
 [27] => Total: 3, online 3 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 10 all 
 [28] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [29] => 0/0 10 1 E0:67:B3:35:CE:9B active online success match 0/0 10 2 E0:67:B3:A6:56:71 active online success match 0/0 10 3 E0:67:B3:A6:25:33 active online success match 
 [30] => Total: 3, online 3 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 11 all 
 [31] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [32] => 0/0 11 1 E0:67:B3:7D:F3:E0 active online success match 
 [33] => Total: 1, online 1 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 12 all 
 [34] => F/S P ONT MAC Control Run Config Match Desc ID flag state state state 
 [35] => 0/0 12 1 E0:67:B3:93:F9:11 active online success match 
 [36] => Total: 1, online 1 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 13 all Error: There is no ONT available. OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 14 all Error: There is no ONT available. OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)#  show ont info 15 all Error: There is no ONT available. OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 16 all Error: There is no ONT available. OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# 
 )
```

and now i need to filter this arrays, and just extract or store in a different array just the arrays starting with

0/0 x x xxxxxxxxxx x x x x x

which basicaly are the cmds replys, which i have requested the 16 cmds which are 16 different ports on the device, and each port replied devices connected on that port  with the data of that device

0/0 1 1 00:00:00:00:00 xxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx

and below update the full telnet cmd reply log for better understanding

```
 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 1 all
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  1  1   AC:4E:91:A6:CF:F5 active    online     success  match     VILERMINA-.
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Total: 1, online 1

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 2 all
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  2  1   E0:E8:E6:4E:62:58 active    online     success  match     CLOVES-NAV.
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Total: 1, online 1

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 3 all
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  3  1   E0:67:B3:93:F1:97 active    online     success  match
   0/0  3  2   18:C5:8A:B0:19:4F active    online     success  match
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Total: 2, online 2

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 4 all
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  4  1   E0:67:B3:A6:45:E1 active    online     success  match     Jessica-Si.
   0/0  4  2   E0:67:B3:7E:20:05 active    online     success  match     onu-id-2
   0/0  4  3   E0:67:B3:7D:F8:F9 active    online     success  match     onu-id-3
   0/0  4  4   E0:E8:E6:4E:69:B8 active    online     success  match     onu-id-4
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Total: 4, online 4

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 5 all
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  5  1   C4:70:0B:26:B9:38 active    online     success  match
   0/0  5  2   E0:67:B3:88:33:E2 active    online     success  match
   0/0  5  3   E0:E8:E6:4E:70:B8 active    powerdown  initial  initial
   0/0  5  4   C4:70:0B:26:5C:28 active    online     success  match
   0/0  5  5   E0:E8:E6:4E:75:C8 active    online     success  match
   0/0  5  6   E0:E8:E6:4E:69:C0 active    online     success  match
   0/0  5  7   E0:67:B3:93:EF:D5 active    online     success  match
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Total: 7, online 6

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 6 all
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  6  1   E0:67:B3:88:3D:57 active    online     success  match
   0/0  6  2   E0:E8:E6:4E:71:08 active    online     success  match
   0/0  6  3   E0:E8:E6:4E:74:78 active    online     success  match
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Total: 3, online 3

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 7 all
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  7  1   00:6D:61:59:D8:48 active    online     success  match
   0/0  7  2   E0:E8:E6:4E:55:20 active    online     success  match
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total: 2, online 2

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 8 all
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  8  1   E0:E8:E6:4E:69:E0 active    online     success  match
   0/0  8  2   E0:E8:E6:4E:70:08 active    online     success  match
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Total: 2, online 2

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 9 all
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  9  1   E0:E8:E6:4E:62:78 active    online     success  match
   0/0  9  2   E0:67:B3:A6:58:0F active    online     success  match
   0/0  9  3   9C:28:EF:01:AE:99 active    online     success  match
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Total: 3, online 3

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 10 all
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  10 1   E0:67:B3:35:CE:9B active    online     success  match
   0/0  10 2   E0:67:B3:A6:56:71 active    online     success  match
   0/0  10 3   E0:67:B3:A6:25:33 active    online     success  match
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Total: 3, online 3

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 11 all
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  11 1   E0:67:B3:7D:F3:E0 active    online     success  match
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total: 1, online 1

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 12 all
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run        Config   Match     Desc
           ID                    flag      state      state    state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0/0  12 1   E0:67:B3:93:F9:11 active    online     success  match
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Total: 1, online 1

 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 13 all
 Error: There is no ONT available.


 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 14 all
 Error: There is no ONT available.


 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 15 all
 Error: There is no ONT available.


 OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 16 all
 Error: There is no ONT available.
```

Comment: hmmm.. but basicaly its an array i am reading from all i have tried throws back the same error preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in

Comment: there are several cmds sent same time.. if i send each cmd separately and fetch the data from the array..i can update it on the mysql table.. but if i try to run all the cmds and get the output results from the array i cannot parse it properly

Comment: Is the array of data in your question the value of `$data_response` or `$sections` or something else?

Comment: @mickmackusa so why did you delete your comment? In the comments I see answers but no questions to go with them which makes it hard to interpret the answers...

Comment: There were multiple comments and they were very long and were bloating the page.  In the end, the asker didn't give me what I wanted.  I just answered based on my perception of the data.

Comment: @0p3nS0urc32015 additional critiques: the `s` pattern modifier is useless if there are no `.` (any character wildcard) characters in the pattern.  And `\r?\n` is more simply covered by `\R`.

Comment: Hi nick.. basicaly it outputs the array result of Sections and aplies a preg_split on it to filter the correct data 0/0 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx and then fetch it as row and compares, if it has count 9 or 8 and applies the correct filter to forward on the mysql query cmd not added on the code that updates the results into a table with  the results

Comment: hi @mickmackusa i did not delete in the comments i added the rest of the code on my first question.. for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother using `preg_split()` to cut your text into sections.  It looks like you are saving the data regardless of what section it is in.

Use `preg_match_all()` with an optional last capture group.

`^` means "match the start of a line" because of the `m` pattern modifier.

`\h*` means "match zero or more whitespace characters that do not represent a newline / line break".

`\h+\` means the same as above except it requires one or more occurrences.

The final horizontal space and visible characters are optional -- this is what the non-capturing group with `?` does.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HCI5E))

```
var_export(
    preg_match_all(
        '~^\h*(\d+/\d+)\h+(\d+)\h+(\d+)\h+([A-F\d]{2}(?::[A-F\d]{2}){5})\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)(?:\h+(\S+))?~m',
        $response,
        $m,
        PREG_SET_ORDER
    )
    ? $m
    : 'no matches'
);
```

See the demo for the sample text and output.

Comment: hi @mickmackusa thanks for your input, i did test it, and this works great for string input.. but the cmd replie from the device prints the output in a array. and preg_match_all needs a string input right? i have tried implode the result from the array before sending it to the var_export function but allways replies back the result :  no matches..

Comment: If the returned data is always an array of single lines and want to filter them, you can just use `array_filter($array, fn($v) => str_starts_with($v, '0/0'))`, then before batch inserting, you can parse the qualifying strings with `sprintf()` or `preg_match()` (or `preg_split()`). Perhaps you can show me the output when you `echo implode("\n", $data_response)`.  Then  i can see what is going wrong.  I prefer 3v4l.org demo links.

Comment: hi , i will attach cmd reply full output.. before implode straight out of the telnet cmd reply.. first array.  on my first post will update the code there

Comment: i have updated my first post with the data ..

Comment: I updated my answer to accommodate the whitespaces in the response text.

Comment: hi @mickmackusa, great thanks, but my first response from the device on the telnet cmd gets stored in array.. so i need to array filter it, or can i implode it to string and try to read as string? will giver ti another try on your code.

Comment: Great i tested it on the first data_response and it parsed the data correclty into the arrays.. so it worked thanks.

Answer (score -1):

as an update the following array code filters the data i need

```
  $res = array_filter($sections, function ($var) { return (strpos($var, ' 0/0 ') == true);});
```

which outputs the final result filtered

```
 Array 
 ( 
 [2] => 0/0 1 1 AC:4E:91:A6:CF:F5 active online success match VILERMINA-. 
 [5] => 0/0 2 1 E0:E8:E6:4E:62:58 active online success match CLOVES-NAV. 
 [8] => 0/0 3 1 E0:67:B3:93:F1:97 active online success match 0/0 3 2 18:C5:8A:B0:19:4F active online success match 
 [11] => 0/0 4 1 E0:67:B3:A6:45:E1 active online success match Jessica-Si. 0/0 4 2 E0:67:B3:7E:20:05 active online success match onu-id-2 0/0 4 3 E0:67:B3:7D:F8:F9 active online success match onu-id-3 0/0 4 4 E0:E8:E6:4E:69:B8 active online success match onu-id-4 
 [14] => 0/0 5 1 C4:70:0B:26:B9:38 active online success match 0/0 5 2 E0:67:B3:88:33:E2 active online success match 0/0 5 3 E0:E8:E6:4E:70:B8 active powerdown initial initial 0/0 5 4 C4:70:0B:26:5C:28 active online success match 0/0 5 5 E0:E8:E6:4E:75:C8 active online success match 0/0 5 6 E0:E8:E6:4E:69:C0 active online success match 0/0 5 7 E0:67:B3:93:EF:D5 active online success match 
 [17] => 0/0 6 1 E0:67:B3:88:3D:57 active online success match 0/0 6 2 E0:E8:E6:4E:71:08 active online success match 0/0 6 3 E0:E8:E6:4E:74:78 active online success match 
 [20] => 0/0 7 1 00:6D:61:59:D8:48 active online success match 0/0 7 2 E0:E8:E6:4E:55:20 active online success match 
 [23] => 0/0 8 1 E0:E8:E6:4E:69:E0 active online success match 0/0 8 2 E0:E8:E6:4E:70:08 active online success match 
 [26] => 0/0 9 1 E0:E8:E6:4E:62:78 active online success match 0/0 9 2 E0:67:B3:A6:58:0F active online success match 0/0 9 3 9C:28:EF:01:AE:99 active online success match 
 [29] => 0/0 10 1 E0:67:B3:35:CE:9B active online success match 0/0 10 2 E0:67:B3:A6:56:71 active online success match 0/0 10 3 E0:67:B3:A6:25:33 active online success match 
 [32] => 0/0 11 1 E0:67:B3:7D:F3:E0 active online success match 
 [35] => 0/0 12 1 E0:67:B3:93:F9:11 active online success match )
```

now i just need to split the rest of the data to prepare the arrays to forward to the query mysql

The arrays need to be split into new arrays

```
 [8] => 0/0 3 1 E0:67:B3:93:F1:97 active online success match 0/0 3 2 18:C5:8A:B0:19:4F active online success match 
 [11] => 0/0 4 1 E0:67:B3:A6:45:E1 active online success match Jessica-Si. 0/0 4 2 E0:67:B3:7E:20:05 active online success match onu-id-2 0/0 4 3 E0:67:B3:7D:F8:F9 active online success match onu-id-3 0/0 4 4 E0:E8:E6:4E:69:B8 active online success match onu-id-4
```

to output

```
 [1] => 0/0 3 1 E0:67:B3:93:F1:97 active online success match 
 [2] => 0/0 3 2 18:C5:8A:B0:19:4F active online success match 
 [3] => 0/0 4 1 E0:67:B3:A6:45:E1 active online success match Jessica-Si. 
 [4] => 0/0 4 2 E0:67:B3:7E:20:05 active online success match onu-id-2 
 [5] => 0/0 4 3 E0:67:B3:7D:F8:F9 active online success match onu-id-3 
 [6] =>0/0 4 4 E0:E8:E6:4E:69:B8 active online success match onu-id-4
```

Comment: A loose comparison on `true` is not stable as a general use technique.